# map the result to the invert ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

in the following code everything works fine,

my problem is the following currently, my map shows me the following result 1 2 3 4 5 ect while I would like the reading to do the other way so that shows me in 1st the last result of my bbd so on 5 4 3 2 1 ect

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { CardText,  Col, Row, } from 'reactstrap'
 import axios from 'axios'

const entrypoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT + '/api';

class HistoriqueForAdmin extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     data: [],
   };
 }

getRandom = async () => {

    const res = await axios.get(
        entrypoint + "/alluserpls"
    )
    this.setState({ data: res.data })
 }
 componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom()
 }
 render() {
    let datas = this.state.data.map(datass => {
        return (
            <div>
              <Col sm="12" key={datass.id}>

                        <CardText>{datass.totalComplet}€</CardText>
                        <CardText  
                </Col>  
            </div>
        )
    })
      return (       
            <div>
              {datas}
            </div>
      )
   }
 }  
export default HistoriqueForAdmin
```

Comment: write as state.data.reverse().map(()=>{})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method for this like:

```
this.state.data.reverse().map(...)
```

DEMO:

The `reverse()` method reverses an array in place. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first.

```js
const array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
console.log('array1:', array1);
// expected output: "array1:" Array ["one", "two", "three"]

const reversed = array1.reverse();
console.log('reversed:', reversed);
// Output: "reversed:" Array ["three", "two", "one"]

// Careful: reverse is destructive -- it changes the original array.
console.log('array1:', array1);
// Output: "array1:" Array ["three", "two", "one"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reverse` function on array before mapping

```
let datas = this.state.data.reverse().map(datass => {
        return (
            <div>
              <Col sm="12" key={datass.id}>

                        <CardText>{datass.totalComplet}€</CardText>
                        <CardText  
                </Col>  
            </div>
        )
    })
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use js method [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
let datas = this.state.data.reverse().map(datass => {
 return (
  <div>
   <Col sm="12" key={datass.id}>
    <CardText>{datass.totalComplet}€</CardText>
    <CardText  
   </Col>  
  </div>
 )
})
```